# Questions Regarding Advanced Case Search

Tags: commcare

I am reassigning cases to different case owners by using the advanced case search method referenced in this wiki here:

https://wiki.commcarehq.org/display/commcarepublic/Advanced+Case+Search.

Is it possible to search cases by the form ID (formid) or the usercase ID (e.g. form.commcare_usercase.case.@case_id) ? The wiki only shows syntax for how to search for cases by name, the lack of a name, case ID, case type, dates, or by whether or not a case is open or closed. I tried to use _formid: to search for relevant cases, but using that syntax did not seem to yield any results. Any input regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks so much for reading!

Answer (score 0):

To search for user cases you can filter by the `commcare-user` case type.

There isn't a way to filter by form ID. Each case could have many form IDs related to it which represent each form that updated the case.

Perhaps you can say more about the specific search criteria you are trying to accomplish.